# Some bot is trying to join my server every 5 or 4 minutes

Tags: minecraft

Some bot named "cuute" is trying to join my server every 5 minutes. I tried banning him, ip banning but nothing works, he joins and joins. Here is a screenshot:[[image]]

I want just to ban him because he is really anoying and makes it hard to read the console

Comment: I've been seeing the same user. I've been adding the IP to my firewall block list every time they try a new ip so that they don't fill the server logs with spam.